# Cuboid pressured container - will the pressure reach the shear pressure of the material?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, pressure, pressure-vessel

I'm having a go at designing a water electrolyser for producing hydrogen. I would like to store the hydrogen with minimal compression effort. Up until the past week I have been thinking about using a reciprocating compressor to compress the hydrogen into a separate storage vessel, but have now had another idea that I need some clarity on.

This is the rough idea that I want to consider:

- I have a **1 cubic meter** aluminium box.
- The aluminium is **0.9mm [1050 grade aluminium alloy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1050_aluminium_alloy)**
- The box is halved so that half is used by the anode and half by the cathode.
- The electrolyser is filled with water & catalyst (such as Potassium Hydroxide, as is typical) to the top of the box, so that there is no water inside the box.
- The electrodes are **10cm** tall (leaving 90~cm for gas to accumulate)
- Based on the area available, (90x50x100cm = **0.45 cubic meters**), assuming the temperature is **21 Degrees celsius**, and the shear strength of [aluminium 1050 alloy](https://www.thyssenkrupp-materials.co.uk/aluminium-1050.html) (**60MPa**), there *should* be a maximum of **16.005kg** of hydrogen that can be stored in the area above the electrolyser without the hydrogen leaking/the aluminium breaking.

Is this realistic, or am I missing something? (The hydrogen volume seems very large considering the other designs I have previously been designing and thinking about can't make anywhere near that amount.)

For reference, I am using the following [hydrogen storage vessel calculator](https://stargatehydrogen.com/documents-and-tools/hydrogen-calculators/) from stargate hydrogen to calculate how much hydrogen can be stored within a given container.

Comment: joint or weld strength? will the sides bow?

Comment: my calcs here say this is 3600 psi; 4600 moles, this pressure seems way too high.  Also not sure why shear strength, a pressurized cube would mostly be experiencing tensile stress.

Comment: @TigerGuy What is the equation that you used to come to that pressure & moles?

Comment: @Boolean PV=nRT